# VB.NET, Visual Studio e Namespaces

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, namespace

Como fazer com que o Visual Studio 2017 + VB.NET crie novas classes já com o namespace, como faz no C#?

Já tentei criar e editar *item templates* utilizando o parâmetro `$itemfolder$`, mas não parece funcionar:

**Template**

```
Namespace $itemfolder$

    Public Class $safeitemrootname$

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**Saída**

```
Namespace $itemfolder$

    Public Class MyClass2

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Já utilizando o parâmetro `$rootnamespace$`, não funciona como deveria:

**Template**

```
Namespace $itemfolder$

    Public Class $safeitemrootname$

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**Saída**

```
Namespace ConsoleApp1

    Public Class MyClass

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**Solution Explorer**

[image]

Eu estava esperando que o namespace fosse `ConsoleApp1.TestNamespace` ou `TestNamespace`.

Tem alguma forma de fazer com que o VS2017 adicione os namespaces automaticamente para novas classes VB.NET?

Sei que o Resharper funciona, mas é pago.

Answer (score 1):

Não, isso não é possível. Visual Basic não suporta o conceito de criação de *namespaces* igual ao do C#, para você criar um projeto "*com várias namespaces padrão*" você deve primeiramente remover a *namespace* padrão do projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde está escrito "Your Application" você deixa vazio, sem escrever nada. Infelizmente é algo bem chato de se fazer.

E para criar um arquivo, só digitar a *namespace* no próprio arquivo:

```
Namespace System
    Public Class ConsoleClone
        Public Shared Sub WriteLine(ByVal text$)
             Console.WriteLine(text)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

E você chamará como:

```
System.ConsoleClone.WriteLine("Olá, mundo!")
```

Para não ser ignorante, eu tentava procurar uma maneira de fazer isso hà muito tempo, e não achei nenhuma. Não sei mesmo se é possível fazer isso, todo meu tempo de programação com Visual Basic me virei deste jeito, e não é tão trabalhoso quanto o esperado.

Comment: O foco era que o VS preenchesse automaticamente o namespace na criação de classes como acontece no C#. Poderia ser com o `$itemfolder$`, que ficaria algo do tipo NomeProjeto.Pasta1.Pasta2 ou Pasta1.Pasta2 (no caso do VB.NET tratar os namespaces de forma diferente do C#). Em testes, no VS2013 funcionava esses Item templates.

Comment: Tentei fazer isso no VS2017, não deu certo, deu erro de sintaxe: http://prntscr.com/fv881h